# Does App store rejects IPAD application not supporting multiple orientations

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have created an IPAD application which supports on Portrait orientation. Before uploading on App Store I wanted to sure about my app getting accepted or rejected. Will my application be rejected if it supports only portrait orientation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are **not** required to support both landscape and portrait orientations for an iPad app, although Apple recommends it.

According to [Apple's Technical Q&A QA1689](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1689.html) on Supporting orientations for iPad apps:

> **Q:  Which orientations should my iPad application support?**
>
> **It is strongly recommended that your application support all orientations.** This includes portrait, portrait upside-down, landscape left and landscape right.
>
> If it is essential that your application run in only one orientation (for instance, portrait only), then you should:
>
> - Launch in your supported orientation, regardless of the current device orientation.
> - Avoid displaying any UI element that tells people to rotate the device.
> - Support both variants of an orientation.

Essentially, if you only support one orientation, make sure that your app specifies that it supports the upside-down version of that orientation as well.

Comment: This document has been **retired**.

Comment: You can refer to this one https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1588/_index.html

Answer (score 2):

I've had multiple apps accepted which only support one orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Application will approved that supports only Portrait orientation. I have developed many application that supports only Portrait orientation.

Comment: Only portrait or portrait upsidedown as well?

Comment: I wanted to ask are both required or only portrait will get approved?

Comment: only portrait will get approved.